# dgv selectionchanged c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, selectionchanged

Im facing a very weird issue, wich should be very simple. 
What im trying to achieve: I have 2 datagrids: 1 with invoiceheaders and 1 with invoiceDetails.

When i click on a particular row from the invoiceheaders, the invoicedetails need to change and show the particular details of that invoice. The event im using for this is `dgvInvoiceHeaders_SelectionChanged`.

So the code in the view:

```
 private void InvoiceListView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int invoiceId = 1;


            invoiceHeadersBinding.DataSource = invoiceListPresenter.getInvoiceHeaders();
            dgvInvoiceHeaders.DataSource = invoiceHeadersBinding;
            setInvoiceHeaderColumns();

            if (dgvInvoiceHeaders.CurrentRow != null)
            {
                Int32.TryParse(dgvInvoiceHeaders.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), out invoiceId);
            }

            dgvInvoiceDetails.DataSource = invoiceListPresenter.getSelectedInvoiceDetails(invoiceId);        
            dgvInvoiceDetails.DataSource = invoiceListPresenter.invoiceDetails;
            setInvoiceDetailColumns();




    }
  private void dgvInvoiceHeaders_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        dgvInvoiceDetails.DataSource = invoiceListPresenter.getSelectedInvoiceDetails(Convert.ToInt32(dgvInvoiceHeaders.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()));

        dgvInvoiceDetails.DataSource = invoiceListPresenter.invoiceDetails;
        setInvoiceDetailColumns();

    }
```

And this is the code of the methods im calling:

```
 public List<tbl_invoices> invoiceHeaders;
   public BindingList<tbl_invoices> getInvoiceHeaders()
   {
       try
       {
           using (var invoices = new DBCrownfishEntities())
           {
               invoices.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
               var invoice = from i in invoices.tbl_invoices
                             select i;

               invoiceHeaders = invoice.ToList();
               var listBinding = new BindingList<tbl_invoices>(invoiceHeaders);
                return listBinding;
           }

       }
       catch (Exception exe)
       {

           throw exe;
       }
   }
  public List<tbl_invoiceDetail> invoiceDetails;
   public BindingList<tbl_invoiceDetail> getSelectedInvoiceDetails(int invoiceID)
   {
       try
       {
           using (var invoices = new DBCrownfishEntities())
           {
               invoices.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
               var invoiceDetail = from i in invoices.tbl_invoiceDetail
                                   where i.InvoiceID == invoiceID
                                   select i;

               invoiceDetails = invoiceDetail.ToList();
               var listBinding = new BindingList<tbl_invoiceDetail>(invoiceDetails);

               return listBinding;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception exe)
       {

           throw exe;
       }

   }
```

But with this example the formload is loaded correctly. But after the event is fired, my invoiceheader datagrid is empty. When i put the text in comment at the method `dgvInvoiceHeaders_selectionChanged()`, I see that both of the datagrids are filled correctly.

A push in the right direction would be very kind.

Comment: What is `setInvoiceDetailColumns()` doing and why are you setting the datasource of the same DGV two times in a row? Also, what's `invoiceListPresenter` and how does it function? Plus I have not understood your question... do you mean that once you've changed your selection in the first datagridview with the invoices, the same one gets empty? Be more detailled with the problem, please.

Comment: @D.Petrov: Maybe i should've mentioned its based on an MVP pattern. But as this had nothing to do on this function i did not mention it. The setInvoiceDetailColumns, are the column options (name, headertext, visibility...). Whenever i test it, the first datagridview is empty yes. Apperently its not getting filled after the event selectionchanged. I don't know why, but it does the trick with the on cell click event.

Comment: You mean that the same code works properly, but just executed in the CellClick event?

Comment: @D.Petrov: yes, thats what i ment.